# Issues running android project on Intellij with OpenCV library

Tags: android, eclipse, git, opencv, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij 13.0.2 and OpenCV 2.4.8 attempting to create an Android 3.0 project.

My partner is building on Eclipse and AIDE with no issues but when I recently pulled from git she had finally started using parts of the OpenCV library. I was able to configure Intellij so that the IDE can see where the imports are coming but when attempt to run or build it tells me:

```
    Error:Error:line (4)java: package org.opencv.core does not exist
    Error:Error:line (5)java: package org.opencv.core does not exist
    Error:Error:line (6)java: package org.opencv.core does not exist
    Error:Error:line (7)java: package org.opencv.core does not exist
    Error:Error:line (8)java: package org.opencv.core does not exist
    Error:Error:line (9)java: package org.opencv.imgproc does not exist
    Error:Error:line (19)java: cannot find symbol
    symbol:   class Scalar
```

I've been digging through the module settings for the past hour to no avail as well as Invalidating and Restarting. I was even able to import just the opencv project and build it with Android 4.0.

I'm running out of ideas but it feels like i'm so close.

Edit: I fixed my compilation issue for now. I was using android SDK 17 to build OpenCV and SDK 10 to build my own code. This seemed to cause a DEX error. Now my target SDK is 17 for everything and it seems to work.

Comment: Are you linking the run-time code into your APK? The project setup instructions at http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html are for Eclipse, ah but a web search finds instructions for Android Studio: http://answers.opencv.org/question/14546/how-to-work-with-opencv4android-in-android-studio/ and more https://www.google.com/search?q=opencv+android+studio . (If you're using IntelliJ, you might want to switch to Android Studio. It's based on IntelliJ, with Google's latest Android dev tools.)